# Partition function for the indistinguishable particles using symmetrization of states

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, partition-function, bosons, identical-particles

In the derivation of the partition function for the the N particle ideal gas, the factor of $\frac{1}{N!}$ does not come naturally. We have to go for symmetrized and asymmetrized state.

So, to derive the canonical partition function, we take the asymmetric state.
$|\vec{k_1},...,\vec{k_N}\rangle= \frac{1}{N!}\sum_P(-1)^PP(|\vec{k_1},...,\vec{k_N}\rangle)$

The density operator $(\hat\rho=\frac{e^{-\beta\hat H}}{Z^N})$ in position basis is
$\langle r_1',...,r_N'|\hat\rho|r_1,...,r_N\rangle= \frac{1}{Z_n}\sum_{\vec{k}}\sum_P\sum_{P'}(-1)^P(-1)^{P'}\langle\vec r_1',...,\vec r_N'|k_{P_1},...,k_{P_N}\rangle\langle k_{P_1},...k_{P_N}|e^{-\beta\hat H}|k_{P_1'},...,k_{P_N'}\rangle\langle k_{P_1'},...,k_{P_n'}|\vec r_1,..\vec r_N\rangle$
It has been said the summation $\sum_k$ that has been used above is a restricted sum over $k$ such that single particle states appear only once.
So, to make the summation unrestricted, we have to multiply the above equation by $\frac{n_1!\times n_2!,...\times n_N!}{N!}$ inside $\sum_k$

I am not able to understand why the summation in the equation is restricted one and how to make it unrestricted?

**Source**.
The above derivation is given in Kardar's Statistical Mechanics of Particles.
[image]

Comment: In the restricted sum, each *unique* state should only appear once.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Actually, I am getting very confused. Here we are just trying to find the density operator in coordinate representation. So by definition of change of basis from momentum to coordinates there is no restriction on $k$, right?. So, why are we considering the summation to be restricted and after that we are making it unrestricted. I am getting completely confused about what is happening?

Comment: As far as I understand it, to get $\rho$ in a coordinate basis, you basically trace over $\rho=e^{-\beta\hat{H}}$ in a different basis (twice), and the easiest basis to do that is a basis where $\hat{H}$ is diagonal, for example on a basis of unique many-particle energy eigenstates. But, for example, product states |112> and |121> have the same energy, and so are the same state according to the Hamiltonian, since you can't tell the particles apart, so if you add both of them you end up double counting. So you need to restrict the sum

Comment: Yes $|112>$ and $|121>$ can have different energy but they are different states. The derivation seems a little confusing to me.

Comment: There might be confusion here due to multiparticle bra and ket defiend with particular ordering of particles or as Slater determinants/permanents.

Comment: @Manu |112> and |121> have the same energy, $2E_1 + E_2$, and *technically* they're identical states, since all the particles are identical. It makes no difference whether particle 2 or particle 3 is in the "2" state - you can't tell the difference between them

Comment: I wasn't quite right in my comment before. States with the same occupation numbers are *completely* identical, not just to the Hamiltonian - for all practical purposes they can't be distinguished, because there's no real difference between, say, particle "1" and particle "2".

Comment: This answer might help, though it's a bit on the technical side: [Why can a multi-particle state |ψ⟩ be uniquely characterized by the occupation numbers of the single particle states?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/560323/why-can-a-multi-particle-state-psi-rangle-be-uniquely-characterized-by-the-o) The point is that any two product states with the same occupation numbers will appear in the same symmetrized wave function, and you only count each wave function once.